Is there any specific timeframe for google cloud access token expiration?
Access tokens for WP Mail SMTP (WordPress plugin) in Google Cloud keep expiring. Our emails stop functioning when this happens. I want to know the specific expiration timeframe for Google Cloud access tokens and why Google does not send notifications regarding this.
Could you provide information on the expiration period of Google Cloud access tokens?

Google OAuth access tokens expire in 3600 seconds. Refresh tokens do not expire but can be canceled/revoked for many reasons which is your problem. I do not recommend using Gmail for server-based mail services. Your solution is to choose a service designed for your use case. Gmail is not one of them.

I will try Mailgun.
